# Can I use "leave" with any gerund?

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerunds

I know that this is correct:

**Jack left teaching last year.**

What about other verbs?

> **Jack left reading the book.**
>
> **Jack left loving her.**
>
> **Jack left visiting his friend.**

I am trying to figure out if there are only some verbs of certain semantics can be used here.

Comment: please share your research with the community. Did you look up the term "leave"? See [Collins entry](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/leave#:~:text=2.-,transitive%20verb,my%20bags%20in%20the%20car.), definition **2**. ***If you leave an institution, group, or job, you permanently stop attending that institution***, being a member of that group, or **doing that job**.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Jack left teaching last year* means that he left (departed from) the teaching profession, not that he ceased to teach. You can use the phrasal verb *leave off* to mean 'stop doing something', but not *leave* on its own.

Comment: It's true that *Jack left teaching* means he left the *profession*. But we'd normally understand that to imply he ceased to teach in any capacity, so I expect that's why someone downvoted your answer. Perhaps you should edit to clarify the point (that ***to leave [gerund]*** specifically and only works with gerunds that represent "professions, careers" or similar; we can't say ***Jack left loving his wife***).